# android mp4parser video appending result of 00:00 duration

Tags: android, mp4parser

hy everyone i am trying to append two videos in android using `mp4parser`, but the problem is that the resultant video is of `00:00` duration although it occupies the size of video1 + video2 both the videos are captured from the same back cam of same handset with exactly same encoding so `encoding` isn't any problem. i've already had a look at the samples referred by the mp4parser official site and it's almost the same code but there seems to be something else thanks in advance
here is my code

```
private void appendVideos() throws IOException
    {
        String f1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/video1.mp4";
        String f2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/video2.mp4";

        Movie[] inMovies;

        inMovies = new Movie[]
                {
                MovieCreator.build(f1),
                MovieCreator.build(f2),
                };


        List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();

        for (Movie m : inMovies) 
        {
            for (Track t : m.getTracks()) 
            {
                if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) 
                {
                    audioTracks.add(t);
                }
                if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) 
                {
                    videoTracks.add(t);
                }
            }
        }

        Movie result = new Movie();

        if (audioTracks.size() > 0) 
        {
            result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
        }
        if (videoTracks.size() > 0) 
        {
            result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks.toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
        }

        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);

        RandomAccessFile ram = new RandomAccessFile(String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/output.mp4"), "rw");
        FileChannel fc = ram.getChannel();
        out.writeContainer(fc);
        ram.close();
        fc.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: @Sebastian Annies can you please help me out???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine with me.

Just do this one change your code will work fine.

Replace the isoparser-1.0-RC-37.jar With isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar in your lib folder.

Download isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar file from below link.
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.mp4parser/isoparser/1.0-RC-27